# Play continuous video stream of NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, metalkit

I am working on a video calling application which involves streaming. I get continuous `NSData` steam in a delegate callback. Could anyone tell me how to render this continuous `NSData` stream in using Objective-C?

Should I use `AVPlayer` or `MetalKit` for rendering the data?

```
- (void) videoReceived: frame:(NSData*) data
```

This delegate method keeps getting called continuously while streaming (this is the place I get video data in the form of `NSData`). Could anyone tell me how to render it?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var videoData: Data // some video data
var fileURL: URL // some local path, preferably appending NSTemporaryDirectory() 
try! videoData.write(to: fileURL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)
```